# Perl Text::Unaccent: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character

Tags: perl, character-encoding

I'm getting the error `Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character` when I try to convert a string with some diacritical marks to it's unaccented counterpart using Perl's `Text::Unaccent` module. The string is taken from a file that I'm processing. The string is `CÚIL BEAG`, which I'm trying to convert into `CUIL BEAG`.

```
use Text::Unaccent;
...
print unac_string('utf-8', $my_string)
```

The `chardet` utility told me:

```
my_file.dat: windows-1252 (confidence: 0.50)
```

...so I tried that charset as well as `utf-16`, `unicode`, `ISO_8859-2` ...
However, if I run it on the command line, like:

```
perl -e ' use strict; use warnings; use Text::Unaccent; my $s = "CÚIL BEAG"; $s = unac_string("utf-8",$s); print "$s\n"; '
```

...it works fine, and converts the letter properly to a plain old 'U'.

If I hardcode the string `CÚIL BEAG` into my script, I get the same error and no conversion.

When I print the string before attempting to convert it, I get `C�IL BEAG`.
The string is undefined after the conversion attempt.

---

I've tried running:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode qw/ encode_utf8 /;
use Text::Unaccent 'unac_string';

open my $fh, '<:encoding(cp1252)', $ARGV[0] or die "Unable to open file: " . $!; # also tried '<:encoding(ISO-8859-1)'

while ( <$fh> ) {
    print $_;
    my $unaccented = unac_string('UTF-8', encode_utf8($_));
    print $unaccented . "\n";
}
```

Supplied file path is to my dat file with just one line in it, containing the string `CÚIL BEAG`. Output is:

```
C�IL BEAG
CUIL BEAG
```

Comment: And what happens if you do `$s = unac_string('utf-8', $my_string); print "$s";` in your script? It maybe that you're trying to print the string before it's been converted perhaps.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. Question is updated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use utf8;                              # Source code is encoded using UTF-8.
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';   # Terminal uses UTF-8.

use Encode         qw( encode_utf8 );
use Text::Unaccent qw( unac_string );

open(my $fh, '<:encoding(cp1252)', $qfn)
   or die("Can't open file \"$qfn\": $!\n");

while (my $uni = <$fh>) {
   my $unaccented = unac_string('UTF-8', encode_utf8($uni));
   print("$uni => $unaccented\n");
}
```

- Well, your file is actually entirely ASCII, so the `use utf8;` doesn't actually do anything.
- The second line tells Perl to decode/encode IO sent to/from STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR/files using UTF-8, since this is what your terminal expects.
- Your particular file, however, is encoded using Windows-1252 aka cp1252, so we'll override the earlier pragma by using an `:encoding` layer.
- `unac_string` expects encoded strings, so we'll reencode it using UTF-8.

Comment: The OP says *"I still need the raw unconverted value in addition to the unnaccented version"* so leaving the data encoded when it's read from the file isn't the right thing for him

Comment: I've tried using your last code snippet on the following input: http://filebin.ca/2Chzf0Csmcaz/accent.dat (it's just got the accented string in it and nothing else). It converts the accented character fine, but the accented character (printed out before conversion) is not recognized (it's a question mark).

Comment: You never encoded your output. What does your terminal expect? I've updated my answer assuming your terminal expects UTF-8.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned earlier that the unusual characters I've been getting for the raw input `CÃºil` are what shows up in a MySQL database after putting it there. If I don't initially open the file with any encoding specified, the raw value put into the database shows up fine as`CUIL`. So, I'm not really bothered about the terminal not displaying the raw string correctly. The DB table that I'm using has `latin1` as the char encoding.

Comment: How do you view the data in the database?

Comment: Do you have phpMyAdmin? I trust it to accurately display what's in the DB.

Comment: I don't. If I don't specify any character encoding when opening the file, everything looks fine. Is that not recommended?

Comment: Your logic shouldn't deal with encoded text. Decode inputs; encode outputs. Do you use `mysql_enable_utf8 => 1`?

Comment: No, I'm not using that option at all.

Comment: Add it to `connect`'s attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `use utf8` to say that the contents of the script are encoded using UTF-8. Then it will work fine with a hard-coded string

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Encode 'encode_utf8';
use Text::Unaccent 'unac_string';

binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(CP-1252)';

my $s = 'CÚIL BEAG';

my $unaccented = unac_string('UTF-8', encode_utf8($s));
say $unaccented;
```

#### output

```
CUIL BEAG
```

You don't show how you're fetching the string from the file, but it needs to be reencoded to Perl internal format correctly. You may find that adding

```
use open qw/ :std IN :encoding(ISO-8859-1) /;
```

at the head of your program will help, or you could specify the encoding when you open the file with

```
open my $fh, '<:encoding(CP-1252)', 'myfile.txt' or die $!;
```

but I can't tell what encoding you should be using without seeing some data

---

It's very straightforward to read from a file once you know the encoding and I'm afraid I can't fathom what you may have done wrong

This program will print the whole of a file encoded in ISO-8859-1 with the accents removed. You should compare it to your own code

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Encode 'encode_utf8';
use Text::Unaccent 'unac_string';

binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(CP-1252)';

open my $fh, '<:encoding(CP-1252)', 'myfile.txt' or die $!;

while ( <$fh> ) {
    my $unaccented = unac_string('UTF-8', encode_utf8($_));
    print $unaccented;
}
```

Comment: So, is it safe / reliable to only use `encode_utf8` without specifying the encoding when opening the file?

Comment: @RTF: No. You have to specify the encoding of the source file

Comment: Fair enough, I will then. It does work for me though, without specifying the encoding when opening the file.

Comment: When I specify the encoding `encoding(ISO-8859-1)`while opening the file, the word `CUIL` changes to `CÃºil`. I still need the raw unconverted value in addition to the unnaccented version. Is there another charset that might work?

Comment: @RTF, What encoding was used to create the file? Alternatively, provide the output of `perl -ne'binmode STDIN; printf("%vX\n", $_)' <my_file.dat`

Comment: @RTF: That's because the extended ASCII characters in ISO-8859-1 happen to have the same encodings as the Unicode character points from 0x80 to 0xFF. That doesn't apply to character sets like CP-1252 which is very slightly different, and your code should say what encoding it's expecting even if there are shortcuts for some encodings

Comment: @ikegami here's a line from the file containing the string in question: http://pastebin.com/HWuK9Kih

Comment: @RTF: That's ISO-8859-1 or something very similar. The sequence `43.DA.49.4C` is `CÚIL`. You'll have to show your code for us to be able to fix it. It translates to `BO~542664~PETER CADOGAN~19 CÚIL BEAG~TRAMORE~CO. WATERFORD~~~~1646579~27/04/2015~~P` is that correct?

Comment: @RTF, That would be iso-8859-1, iso-8859-15 or cp1252. Both snippets in my answer work (now that I fixed them so they run at all).

Comment: @Borodin see comment in Itegami's comment section about code snippet, also applies to your last code snippet

Comment: You need to `binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(CP-1252)';` at the top of your program if your terminal is expecting encoded characters. That may need to be `ISO-8859-1` instead, or even something else. Essentially your output encoding has to match what the terminal is expecting or it will display the wrong characters. My Windows terminal defaults to CP-850 so I wrote `binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(CP-850)';` and my code worked fine with your real data. If you're not sure what it's expecting then just enter the command `chcp` and it will tell you. I've changed my code to give you an example